# Locally disable padding

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I write a parser for some data structure, after hours of debugging I found out that the problem is Visual Studio doesn't interpret the structures as I tell it. It seems some "padding" is used

```
struct foo { 
unsigned char a; //0x00
unsigned char b; //0x01
unsigned int c; //0x02
unsigned int d; //0x06
unsigned int e; //0x0A
unsigned int f; //0x0E
//0x12
};
```

I expected "sizeof(foo)=4*4+2=18" but I get "sizeof(foo)=20". Is there any possibility to turn padding off just for this special struct? I tried

```
__declspec(align(1)) struct foo { ...
```

but it does not work. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I think [this article on MSDN will help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253935%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Are you compiling with `/Zp 1`?

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst That would globally disable padding, The solution of hans works.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the `#pragma pack` directive for that:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct foo { 
  // etc..
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

Answer (score 4):

Visual Studio 2010 has [`#pragma pack`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e70t5y1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to do what you're looking for.

Comment: But wouldn't that affect all structs? I just want it locally for that one struct.

Comment: You can revert it afterwards - did you even read that documentation?

Comment: You can use #pragma pack push/pop to get around that. Just push before and pop after the struct.